# Cambiar el botón para abrir un Navigation Drawer en Android

Tags: java, android

os cuento:

Tengo un Bottom Navigation View al cual le añadi un icono hamburguesa para que en un futuro tuviera un Nagivation Drawer, y ese futuro ha llegado, quiero añadir a ese botón la funcionalidad para abrir el Navigation Drawer, pero no tengo ni idea de como es. Quiero que el botón de la siguiente imagen abra el Navigation Drawer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para manejar los eventos del Bottom Navigation uso un switch que es el siguiente:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        Fragment selectedFragment = null;


        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.btnHome:

                selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                loadFragment(selectedFragment);
                break;

            case R.id.btnFinder:

                selectedFragment = new FinderFragment();
                loadFragment(selectedFragment);
                break;

            case R.id.btnNotes:

                selectedFragment = new NotesFragment();
                loadFragment(selectedFragment);
                break;

            case R.id.btnAdd:

                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FormSelectionActivity.class));
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

};
```

Supongo que tengo que meter algo dentro del evento del botón hamburguesa (el cual no aparece en el código aún, pero para que os hagáis una idea. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define una variable

```
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
```

En `onCreate()` puedes obtener la referencia del `DrawerLayout` (define el id del botón).

```
drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

ahora agrega un nuevo caso a tu listener (define el id del botón):

```
  case R.id.btnHamburger:
                     drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
                break;
```

si deseas cerrarlo usa:

```
             drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
```

Comment: He editado añadiendo una imagen a ver si así se entiende mejor

Comment: ok quieres que desde el botón indicado se abra el NavigationDrawer? :)

Comment: exacto, esa es la idea! :)

Comment: @Isaac he agregado una actualización

Comment: genial, funciona perfecto con una únida modificación, mi Navigation Drawer sale desde la derecha, por lo que en vez de Gravity.START he tenido que ponerle Gravity.END, pero muchas gracias por la pronta y clara respuesta :)

Comment: OK, si este código supone que el Drawer se abre de derecha a izquierda, si es el derecho hacia la izquierda, cambias a drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END); como lo comentas, saludos!